# How to order "group" of row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

This is the query:

```
SELECT WorkTypeId, WorktypeWorkID, LevelID
FROM Worktypes as w
LEFT JOIN WorktypesWorks as ww on w.ID = ww.WorktypeID
LEFT JOIN WorktypesWorksLevels as wwl on ww.ID = wwl.WorktypeWorkID
```

This is the result:

```
WorkTypeId  WorktypeWorkID  LevelID
1           1               1
1           1               2
1           1               3
1           2               1
1           2               2
1           2               3
1           3               1
1           4               1
1           4               2
1           5               1
NULL        NULL            NULL
3           19              2
4           6               1
4           7               1
4           7               2
4           7               3
4           17              1
4           17              2
4           18              1
4           18              2
NULL        NULL            NULL
```

I'd like to order the block of rows of each WorktypeWorkID, placing at the top the blocks which have the lower LevelID within the block.

Here's the result that I'd like to get:

```
WorkTypeId  WorktypeWorkID  LevelID
    NULL        NULL            NULL    
    NULL        NULL            NULL        
    1           3               1       // blocks which have MinLevel 1
    1           5               1   
    4           6               1
    1           4               1       // blocks which have MinLevel 2
    1           4               2   
    3           19              2
    4           17              1
    4           17              2
    4           18              1
    4           18              2       
    1           1               1       // blocks which have MinLevel 3
    1           1               2
    1           1               3
    1           2               1
    1           2               2
    1           2               3
    4           7               1
    4           7               2
    4           7               3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT WorkTypeId, WorktypeWorkID, LevelID, MAX(LevelID) OVER (PARTITION BY WorktypeWorkID) as maxLevelID
FROM Worktypes as w
LEFT JOIN WorktypesWorks as ww on w.ID = ww.WorktypeID
LEFT JOIN WorktypesWorksLevels as wwl on ww.ID = wwl.WorktypeWorkID

ORDER BY maxLevelID
```

Comment: Nope. This will move the "single" row at the top/bottom. I need to move the "block" of all rows having the same WorktypeWorkID

Comment: It takes the min per block.  Look at the OVER () clause.  Did you actually try it?

Comment: My fault, you were right! Only, its MAX() and not MIN(). Thanks

Comment: edit the anwser writing MAX, so I can upvote it ;))